# Binary Operads sample program

Tags: c++, stack, postfix-notation, rpn

**Problem Statement** :
Write a C++ program to evaluate postfix expressions. Your program should take postfix expression as an input, process it with the help of stack and display the result after performing required calculations.

Only following Binary operators are allowed for this program:
+, -, *, /, ^ [addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, exponentiation]

If some error occurs while processing postfix expression, your program should display a meaningful message, like:
Error: Division by zero not allowed
Error: Two operands required for __ operator
Error: Invalid postfix expression

**Help me with it, My program is generating errors** This is my try:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cstring>
#include<string>

#define MAX_SIZE 20

using namespace std;
template<class T>
class Stack
{
private:
    T item[MAX_SIZE];
    int top;
public:
    Stack()
    {
        top = -1;
    }

    void push(T data)
    {
        if(!this->is_full())
            item[++top] = data;
        else
        {
            cout<<"Stack Error"<<endl;
            exit(10);
        }
    }
    T pop()
    {
        if(!this->is_empty())
            return item[top--];
        else
        {
            cout<<"Stack is Empty"<<endl;
            exit(11);
        }
    }

    int size()
    {
        return top+1;
    }

    bool is_empty()
    {
        if(top==-1)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    bool is_full()
    {
        if(top==MAX_SIZE-1)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    void display()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<this->size(); i++)
        {
            cout<<item[i]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    T return_top()
    {
        return item[top];
    }
};

class Convert
{
private:
    bool num_flag;
    bool tow_digit_flag;
public:
    Convert();
    string return_with_bracket(string infix);
    void to_Postfix(string infix,char postfix[]);
    bool prcd(char op1, char op2);
    int isOperand(char op);
    int isOperator(char op);
    bool return_flag()
    {
        return num_flag;
    }
};

Convert::Convert()
{
    this->num_flag = false;
    this->tow_digit_flag = false;
}
string Convert::return_with_bracket(string infix)
{
    return("(" + infix + ")");
}

bool Convert::prcd(char op1, char op2)
{
    if((op1=='+' || op1=='-' || op1=='*' || op1=='/') && op2=='(' )
        return true;
    if(op1=='+' && op2=='+')
        return true;
    if(op1=='-' && op2=='-')
        return false;
    if(op1=='-' && op2=='+')
        return false;
    if(op1=='+' && op2=='-')
        return false;
    if(op1=='/' && op2=='/')
        return false;
    if(op1=='/' && (op2=='-' || op2=='+'))
        return true;
    if(op1=='*' && (op2=='+' || op2=='-'))
        return true;
    if((op1 == '-' || op1 == '+') && (op2 =='*' || op2 == '/'))
        return false;
    if((op1=='$' || op1 == '+') && (op2 =='*' || op2 == '/' || op2=='-'))
        return true;
    if((op1 == '-' || op1 == '+' || op1 =='*' || op1 == '/')&& op2=='^')
        return false;
    if(op1 == '^' && ( op2 == '+' || op2 =='*' || op2 == '/' || op2=='-'))
        return false;
}

int Convert::isOperand(char op)
{
    return(op>= '0' && op <= '9');
}

int Convert::isOperator(char op)
{
    return(op=='+' || op=='-' || op == '/' || op=='*' || op=='^');
}

void Convert::to_Postfix(string infix, char postfix[])
{
    int position, outpos=0;
    char c;
    int count = 0;
    char temp;
    char stacktop ;
    Stack<char> stack;
    for(position = 0; (c = infix[position])!='\0'; position++)
    {
        if(this->isOperand)
        {
            postfix[outpos++] = c;
            this->num_flag = true;
            count++;
            if(count>=2)
            {
                this->tow_digit_flag = true;
            }
        }
        else if(this->isOperator©)
        {
            count = 0;
            if(isOperator(infix[position]) && isOperator(infix[position+1]))
            {
                cout<<"\aMissing argument in between "<<infix[position]<<" and "<<infix[position+1]
                    <<" in column "<< position+1<<endl;
                exit(9);
            }
            if(this->prcd(c, stacktop))
            {
                stacktop=stack.return_top();
                stack.push©;
                stacktop = c;
            }
            else
            {
                while(true)
                {
                    temp = stack.pop();
                    postfix[outpos++] =temp;
                    stacktop = stack.return_top();
                    if(prcd(c, stacktop) || stacktop=='(')
                        break;
                }
                stack.push©;
                stacktop = stack.return_top();
            }
        }
        else if(c=='(')
        {
            count = 0;
            stack.push©;
            stacktop = stack.return_top();
        }
        else if(c==')')
        {
            count = 0;
            while(1)
            {
                if(stack.size()==0)
                {
                    cout<<"Warning!! Number of ')' is greater than '('" <<endl;
                    exit(2);
                }
                temp = stack.pop();
                if(temp!='(')
                {
                    postfix[outpos++] = temp;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            stacktop =stack.return_top();
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"Invalid input";
            exit(3);
        }
        if(infix[position]==')' && infix[position+1]=='(')
        {
            stack.push('*');
            stacktop = stack.return_top();
        }
    }
    if(stack.size()!=0)
    {
        cout<<"Warning!!Number of '(' is greater than ')'"<<endl;
        // exit(6);
    }
    if(!this->return_flag())
    {
        cout<<"You must Enter Numeric value for calculation"<<endl;
        cout<<"This program cannot perform operations on variables";
        exit(5);
    }
    if(this->tow_digit_flag)
    {
        cout<<"Sory! Althoug u may have entered right string"<<endl;
        cout<<"this program is only for single digit operation"<<endl;
        exit(8);
    }
    postfix[outpos] = '\0';
}

class Evaluate
{
public:
    double eval(char expr[], Convert &Wink;
                double oper(int symb, double op1, double op2);
};
double Evaluate::oper(int symb, double op1, double op2)
{
    switch(symb)
    {
    case '+':
        return (op1 + op2);
    case '-':
        return (op1 - op2);
    case '*':
        return (op1 * op2);
    case '/':
        return (op1 / op2);
    case '^':
        return (pow(op1, op2));
    }
}
double Evaluate::eval(char expr[],Convert &convert)
{
    int c, position;
    char temp1;
    int count = 0;
    double opnd1, opnd2, value;
    Stack<double> stack;
    for(position = 0; (c = expr[position])!='\0'; position++)
    {
        if(convert.isOperand©)
        {
            temp1 = double(c-'0');
            stack.push(temp1);
        }
        else
        {
            opnd2 = stack.pop();
            if(stack.size()==0)
            {
                cout<<"This program cannot process unary operation";
                exit(1);
            }
            opnd1 = stack.pop();
            value = oper(c, opnd1, opnd2);
            stack.push(value);
        }
    }
    if(stack.size()>=2)
    {
        cout<<"Sory! this program cannot calculate this"<<endl;
        cout<<"Enter +, *, /, - or ^ between bracket"<<endl;
        exit(4);
    }

    return (stack.pop());
}
int main()
{
    Convert convert;
    Evaluate evaluate;
    string bracketted_infix;
    char infix[50], postfix[50];
    char choice;
    while(1)
    {
        cout<<"Enter operation: ";
        cin>>infix;
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<"Entered operation: "<<infix<<endl;
        bracketted_infix = convert.return_with_bracket(infix);
        convert.to_Postfix(bracketted_infix, postfix);
        cout<<"Equivalent Postfix operation: "<<postfix<<endl;
        cout<<"RESULT: ";
        cout<<evaluate.eval(postfix, convert);
        cout<<"\nCalculate another operation?(y/n) ";
        cin>>choice;
        cout<<endl;
        if(choice=='n')
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting?

Comment: You program inside word processing applications? `(c)` becoming `©`...

Comment: Can you post a smaller program that has the problems? It might even help you find the problem yourself. http://sscce.org/

Comment: Try to use std::stack. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56fa1zk5%28v=vs.71%29.aspx instead writing your own class. At least it will simplify your debugging.

Comment: ohmygod i loved this assignment. http://ideone.com/GiT4S

Comment: that is in C, by the way

Comment: @Benoit oh dear...this is going to be interesting

Comment: @tekknolagi and here I was thinking: "This looks like a well written program, maybe there is hope after all"

Comment: Actually fixing the compile errors and we have what looks like a working program to me. I didn't test all code paths but addition and multiplication and operator precedence at least works.

Comment: @r_ahlskog which program are you talking about? mine or his? if mine, i see no compile errors, and operator precedence doesn't exist in postfix languages

Comment: @tekknolagi his program actually, yours I just took as working as intended and not part of the discussion. His program converts infix to postfix and I just had to test the precedence code since VS2008 was screaming bloody murder about it and from a quick look it looked like a good place for a bug. And since he sounded like he had partly given up I wanted to offer up some hope that fixing the compile errors would in fact produce something that was not entirely broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get it actually compiling you need to fix two syntax errors;

On line 154 you are calling a method with no parameter,
but the only declaration of this method takes 1 parameter.

```
if (this->isOperand) {
```

I believe you may have meant:

```
if (this->isOperand(c)) {
```

Also on line 255 you have a missing bracket before the semicolon:

```
double eval(char expr[], Convert &Wink;
```

When I actually ran your code it failed at runtime, with VS2010 giving an error "string subscript out of range".

If you're not already, I would recommend using a good IDE (such as Visual C++) when developing; the syntax colouring and support for dynamic debugging (i.e. breakpoints and watches) would be very helpful to debug a program like this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the final solution

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cstring>
#include<string>

#define MAX_SIZE 20

using namespace std;
template<class T>
class Stack
{
private:
    T item[MAX_SIZE];
    int top;
public:
    Stack()
    {
        top = -1;
    }

    void push(T data)
    {
        if(!this->is_full())
            item[++top] = data;
        else
        {
            cout<<"Stack Error"<<endl;
            exit(10);
        }
    }
    T pop()
    {
        if(!this->is_empty())
            return item[top--];
        else
        {
            cout<<"Stack is Empty"<<endl;
            exit(11);
        }
    }

    int size()
    {
        return top+1;
    }

    bool is_empty()
    {
        if(top==-1)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    bool is_full()
    {
        if(top==MAX_SIZE-1)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    void display()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<this->size(); i++)
        {
            cout<<item[i]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    T return_top()
    {
        return item[top];
    }
};

class Convert
{
private:
    bool num_flag;
    bool tow_digit_flag;
public:
    Convert();
    string return_with_bracket(string infix);
    void to_Postfix(string infix,char postfix[]);
    bool prcd(char op1, char op2);
    int isOperand(char op);
    int isOperator(char op);
    bool return_flag()
    {
        return num_flag;
    }
};

Convert::Convert()
{
    this->num_flag = false;
    this->tow_digit_flag = false;
}
string Convert::return_with_bracket(string infix)
{
    return("(" + infix + ")");
}

bool Convert::prcd(char op1, char op2)
{
    if((op1=='+' || op1=='-' || op1=='*' || op1=='/') && op2=='(' )
        return true;
    if(op1=='+' && op2=='+')
        return true;
    if(op1=='-' && op2=='-')
        return false;
    if(op1=='-' && op2=='+')
        return false;
    if(op1=='+' && op2=='-')
        return false;
    if(op1=='/' && op2=='/')
        return false;
    if(op1=='/' && (op2=='-' || op2=='+'))
        return true;
    if(op1=='*' && (op2=='+' || op2=='-'))
        return true;
    if((op1 == '-' || op1 == '+') && (op2 =='*' || op2 == '/'))
        return false;
    if((op1=='$' || op1 == '+') && (op2 =='*' || op2 == '/' || op2=='-'))
        return true;
    if((op1 == '-' || op1 == '+' || op1 =='*' || op1 == '/')&& op2=='^')
        return false;
    if(op1 == '^' && ( op2 == '+' || op2 =='*' || op2 == '/' || op2=='-'))
        return false;
}

int Convert::isOperand(char op)
{
    return(op>= '0' && op <= '9');
}

int Convert::isOperator(char op)
{
    return(op=='+' || op=='-' || op == '/' || op=='*' || op=='^');
}

void Convert::to_Postfix(string infix, char postfix[])
{
    int position, outpos=0;
    char c;
    int count = 0;
    char temp;
    char stacktop ;
    Stack<char> stack;
    for(position = 0; (c = infix[position])!='\0'; position++)
    {
     if (this->isOperand(c)) 

        {
            postfix[outpos++] = c;
            this->num_flag = true;
            count++;
            if(count>=2)
            {
                this->tow_digit_flag = true;
            }
        }
        else if(this->isOperator(c))
        {
            count = 0;
            if(isOperator(infix[position]) && isOperator(infix[position+1]))
            {
                cout<<"\aMissing argument in between "<<infix[position]<<" and "<<infix[position+1]
                    <<" in column "<< position+1<<endl;
                exit(9);
            }
            if(this->prcd(c, stacktop))
            {
                stacktop=stack.return_top();
                stack.push(c);
                stacktop = c;
            }
            else
            {
                while(true)
                {
                    temp = stack.pop();
                    postfix[outpos++] =temp;
                    stacktop = stack.return_top();
                    if(prcd(c, stacktop) || stacktop=='(')
                        break;
                }
                stack.push(c);
                stacktop = stack.return_top();
            }
        }
        else if(c=='(')
        {
            count = 0;
            stack.push(c);
            stacktop = stack.return_top();
        }
        else if(c==')')
        {
            count = 0;
            while(1)
            {
                if(stack.size()==0)
                {
                    cout<<"Warning!! Number of ')' is greater than '('" <<endl;
                    exit(2);
                }
                temp = stack.pop();
                if(temp!='(')
                {
                    postfix[outpos++] = temp;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            stacktop =stack.return_top();
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"Invalid input";
            exit(3);
        }
        if(infix[position]==')' && infix[position+1]=='(')
        {
            stack.push('*');
            stacktop = stack.return_top();
        }
    }
    if(stack.size()!=0)
    {
        cout<<"Warning!!Number of '(' is greater than ')'"<<endl;
        // exit(6);
    }
    if(!this->return_flag())
    {
        cout<<"You must Enter Numeric value for calculation"<<endl;
        cout<<"This program cannot perform operations on variables";
        exit(5);
    }
    if(this->tow_digit_flag)
    {
        cout<<"Sory! Althoug u may have entered right string"<<endl;
        cout<<"this program is only for single digit operation"<<endl;
        exit(8);
    }
    postfix[outpos] = '\0';
}

class Evaluate
{
public:
    double eval(char expr[], Convert &Wink);
                double oper(int symb, double op1, double op2);
};
double Evaluate::oper(int symb, double op1, double op2)
{
    switch(symb)
    {
    case '+':
        return (op1 + op2);
    case '-':
        return (op1 - op2);
    case '*':
        return (op1 * op2);
    case '/':
        return (op1 / op2);
    case '^':
        return (pow(op1, op2));
    }
}
double Evaluate::eval(char expr[],Convert &convert)
{
    int c, position;
    char temp1;
    int count = 0;
    double opnd1, opnd2, value;
    Stack<double> stack;
    for(position = 0; (c = expr[position])!='\0'; position++)
    {
        if(convert.isOperand(c))
        {
            temp1 = char(c-'0');
            stack.push(temp1);
        }
        else
        {
            opnd2 = stack.pop();
            if(stack.size()==0)
            {
                cout<<"This program cannot process unary operation";
                exit(1);
            }
            opnd1 = stack.pop();
            value = oper(c, opnd1, opnd2);
            stack.push(value);
        }
    }
    if(stack.size()>=2)
    {
        cout<<"Sory! this program cannot calculate this"<<endl;
        cout<<"Enter +, *, /, - or ^ between bracket"<<endl;
        exit(4);
    }

    return (stack.pop());
}
int main()
{
    Convert convert;
    Evaluate evaluate;
    string bracketted_infix;
    char infix[50], postfix[50];
    char choice;
    while(1)
    {
        cout<<"Enter operation: ";
        cin>>infix;
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<"Entered operation: "<<infix<<endl;
        bracketted_infix = convert.return_with_bracket(infix);
        convert.to_Postfix(bracketted_infix, postfix);
        cout<<"Equivalent Postfix operation: "<<postfix<<endl;
        cout<<"RESULT: ";
        cout<<evaluate.eval(postfix, convert);
        cout<<"\nCalculate another operation?(y/n) ";
        cin>>choice;
        cout<<endl;
        if(choice=='n')
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```